Need Vlookup and Indirect Formula
I've never used the Indirect formula so looking for some help.
I want to reference the Offer # on the 'Summary' tab to look up the Total Qty Ordered value on the tab titled #1.
So, for Offer #1 (cell A3) on the Summary tab, look up on the tab titled "1", vlookup the offer # (cell b1) and return the Qty Ordered value (cell D1) into cell H3 on the Summary tab.
Summary tab
Offer 1 tab
I cant find examples that are set up the same way I have mine, and unable to set up the formula correctly.
Thanks for any assistance.
I've tried the below formula, but returning a reference error
=VLOOKUP($A3, INDIRECT("'"&B$1 &"'!"&"B1:D1"), 3, 0)
My expected return is value '5' as that is the Qty Ordered value on tab 1, cell D1

$B$1 needs to be A3, so try =VLOOKUP($A3, INDIRECT(CONCAT(A3, "!", "B1:D1")), 3, 0) if the sheets will be named without spaces; otherwise try =VLOOKUP($A3, INDIRECT(CONCAT("'", A3, "'", "!", "B1:D1")), 3, 0). Though & is fine, CONCAT makes it easier to read I think.

Also, from the format of the offer tab, it looks like you may not need VLOOKUP, just INDIRECT(CONCAT("'", A3, "'", "!", "B1:D1")) would suffice.

perfect! thank you!

Glad to hear it :)
